# Request to allow restoration of HDD sectors image

Tags: backup, restore, sectors, bypass, raw

I took apart my Creative Nomad Zen Xtra and opened the HDD up in HXD.exe then saved all the sectors to my d: drive so I could use the HDD for something else temporarily but then I realized I need something to restore the sectors from the sector dump back on to the HDD. So I thought Rufus can do this. It lists the drive but then even with "Non bootable" selected it warns me that the image is not a bootable image. I know it is not a bootable image, I just want to restore the sectors. How do I bypass the warning about it not being bootable and write the sectors regardless?

Comment: If you actually *"saved all the sectors"* as an image of the entire drive, then the Linux **dd** command is the simplest utility to perform a restore of the image file to the drive.  BTW suggest you rewrite the title.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have linux. I don't know anything about it. I just use Windows. HXD is a Windows Hex editor which can edit HDD sectors also, or save them. But it can't restore them all, it runs out of memory. So I was hoping to use Rufus to restore the sectors. I thought for sure it could do this with the non bootable drop down but it didn't work.

Comment: Inspect the first 512 bytes of the saved *"image"* file.  Does it look like the MBR sector?  BTW avoid the brief summations of what you did and the results.  Instead provide the actual commands used, and the resulting messages.

Comment: It is a creative nomad jukebox zen xtra, it does not use known boot sectors.  The first sector is HEX 42 4D 4B 4C 00 00 00 02 7E 03 40 3E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 A0 00 00 01 00 6D 00 69 00 6E 00 69 00 66 00 73 00 00 00 00 00 7D 03 3F 9E 00 00 01 A0 63 00 66 00 73 followed by many 00 I don't need to troubleshoot anything. I am just asking for a feature that allows raw restoration of sector dump files. The non bootable option should do this, so maybe it is a bug that it doesn't.  I understand if nobody wants to add the feature and appreciate the time.

Comment: If you don't like restrictions and/or want more built-in capabilities, then learn how to use Linux.  With root privileges, a basic **dd** command will perform the sector-by-sector copy.  Try downloading a Debian or  Mint "LiveCD", and create a bootable DVD or USB flash drive for a PC.

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** want to do it with Rufus, there's a [cheat-mode](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Power_keysCheat_modes) that allows you to open non bootable DD images for writing:

- `Alt`-`M`

However, that will only work if Rufus lists the target disk, which isn't a given for internal drives (though you say that it does, so I am going to assert that your HDD is plugged through USB).

Also, you could have used Rufus to [save a VHD image of your drive](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Saving_an_existing_drive_to_VHD) instead of using HxD. For all purposes and intents (uncompressed) VHD images like the ones created by Rufus, are the same as DD images and in fact, they can be used exactly like a DD image (meaning that, if you want to, you can use `dd` on Linux with a `.vhd` to restore a disk), with the advantage that, if using Windows, you will also be able to *mount* the VHD image as a virtual drive, which can be quite convenient.